# Screenshots are not coming in index.html for geb spock appium

Tags: appium, spock, geb, spock-reports

I am using Geb Spock with Appium. I am successfully able to execute the script with it and reports are too getting generated. However screen shots are getting attached in index.html summary report. When I searched for screenshots in target folder, then observed that screenshots are present there but  below error is coming in logs which might be the reason why screen shots are getting attached under index.html.

Error:

```
Jul 12, 2018 12:29:40 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorCodes toStatus
INFO: HTTP Status: '404' -> incorrect JSON status mapping for 'unknown method' (405 expected)
Unexpected error while creating report for label '001-001-Step 1:Go to the login page of the WU-Step 1 is completed: org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: Method has not yet been implemented
Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T14:04:26.12Z'
```

I am not facing any issues when I am executing test scripts for my web application, however I am not sure why this is not working with Appium.
Please let me know if I need to provide more information on this.
Can you please help me on this. Thanks!

Comment: Have you written any custom reporting code?  Are you saying you are getting the expected reports, but an error is being thrown?

Comment: Nope. I am using spock-reports plugin provided by renoto athaydes only.